# Can I accept a prefix argument based on another argument within an `(interactive ...)` form?

Tags: elisp, interactive, prefix-argument

```
(defun tmp:interactive (&optional scope pos-style)
  "POS-STYLE has no effect when SCOPE is `directory'."
  (interactive
   (list
    (cdr (assoc (read-char-choice
                 "Copy (f)ull name, (d)irectory, or just the (b)asename? "
                 '(?f ?d ?b))
                '((?f . full)
                  (?d . directory)
                  (?b . basename))))
    (when (and (not (equal scope 'directory)) current-prefix-arg)
      (cdr (assoc (read-char-choice
                   "Style: (n)one, (l)ine, (c)olumn, or (p)oint? "
                   '(?n ?l ?c ?p))
                  '((?n . nil)
                    (?l . line)
                    (?c . line-column)
                    (?p . point)))))))
  (message "%S %S" scope pos-style))
```

Above is a skeleton of a function that copies the appropriate file name for the current buffer.  However, it doesn't really make sense to include position information when the user is copying the directory name.

Is there a way to ignore a prefix argument within the `(interactive ...)` form based on previous input?

(An alternative solution to this end would be to test `called-interactively-p` and leave the optional argument as nil to test in the body of the `defun`, but that's very fragmented.

Comment: See the [finished use case](https://github.com/vermiculus/dotfiles/commit/23a19f572e008b1f07ecc708ff51618496dfbf5f).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot refer to `SCOPE` within the `interactive` form, because it is that form that defines `SCOPE`.

What you can do is use `let` to save the result of `read-char-choice` and then test that in the rest of the `interactive` spec.

```el
(defun tmp:interactive (&optional scope pos-style)
  "POS-STYLE has no effect when SCOPE is `directory'."
  (interactive
   (let ((scop  (cdr (assoc (read-char-choice
                             "Copy (f)ull name, (d)irectory, or just the (b)asename? "
                             '(?f ?d ?b))
                            '((?f . full)
                              (?d . directory)
                              (?b . basename))))))

     (list scop (and (not (equal scop 'directory))
                     current-prefix-arg
                     (cdr (assoc (read-char-choice
                                  "Style: (n)one, (l)ine, (c)olumn, or (p)oint? "
                                  '(?n ?l ?c ?p))
                                 '((?n . nil)
                                   (?l . line)
                                   (?c . line-column)
                                   (?p . point))))))))
  (message "%S %S" scope pos-style))
```

Comment: That's why I figured it didn't work. I did think of doing something like that (naïvely using `setq`, though), but I couldn't figure a way to get around the scoping issue.  Can you provide an example using a `let`-binding?

Comment: See above.  Also, you don't need `when` here; it is extra.  What's more, many people (me too) prefer to not use `when` when the return value is important.  We use `when` and `until` only for side effects.  This makes it easier for humans to understand the code (the intent).

Comment: Good points about side-effects; I'll keep that in mind for future development.  And ah!! It seems so simple now that you laid it out! Thanks :)

Comment: By the way, you don't *need* to use `scop` rather than `scope` here – is that another style choice?

Comment: Yes, it just makes it easier to read (IMO). You saw how easy it was to confuse the input parameter with using it inside `interactive'. This helps human readers realize that this local variable is not the same thing. It is true that a function parameter cannot be a dynamic variable in Emacs Lisp, but it's best to help readers avoid any confusion here (IMO).

Comment: Good points. Code is mostly for the reader – the compiler should be an after-thought.  (Overly generalized, but I think I made the point…)

Comment: Drew: I'm curious; do you also avoid returning important values from an `if` expression? I'd be rather surprised if that's the case, but to me `when` and `unless` are just better (*more* obvious/readable) variants of `if` when no 'else' expression is needed, because the reader knows immediately that this is the case, without having to look for the indentation. It surprises me to hear them described as more confusing to the reader.

Comment: @phils: No. I use `if` when the result matters. And instead of a single-branch `if`, I use either `and` or `when`/`unless`, depending on whether the return value is important or the branch is used only for side effects. In sum, I don't use a single-branch `if`, and I use `when` and `unless` only when the result is not important. I never want the code to depend on the `nil` result returned by `when` or `unless`.

Comment: @phils: In this case, the `when` in the OP was doubly inappropriate: (a) unnecessary and (b) incorrect, since it returns `nil`.

Comment: @phils: I don't think I said anywhere that `when` and `unless` are more confusing. I agree 100% that it is clear that there is a single branch when they are used. But I adhere to an old Common Lisp convention that they signal (to humans) that the value returned is unimportant. So when the return value matters I use `cond`, `if` (if > 1 branch), `and`, and `or`, with `progn` if necessary.

Comment: Drew: Right; I had inferred "less confusing" from the "easier for humans to understand" part, but as it's actually a matter of convention, that makes more sense. I don't have a Common Lisp background, so the convention seems awfully strange, but I appreciate the explanation.

Comment: @phils: What seems strange about it? `when` and `unless` return `nil`, so their return value is already uninteresting. Using them not for their return value (only for side effects) is no big change. Using `if` only for > 1 branch coincides with what you say about it being not obvious (`when` is more obvious). I don't understand what seems "awfully strange" (or even a little bit strange). What am I missing?

Comment: Drew: `(when cond "foo")` and `(unless cond "foo")` return either `nil` or `"foo"`. Is that different to Common Lisp? You make it sound like they return `nil` in all situations.

Comment: @phils: Oh, right. So scratch that point. ;-)  I still use `if`,...`and`, `or` to indicate that the value matters, and `when`, `unless` to indicate that it does not.

Comment: @phils: This is what I follow, from [CLTL2](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node84.html): "*As a matter of style, `when` is normally used to conditionally produce some side effects, and the value of the `when` form is normally not used. If the value is relevant, then it may be stylistically more appropriate to use `and` or `if`.*"

Comment: Thanks Drew, it's all clear to me now. The convention is a little at odds to how I think, so I'm not sure I'll adopt it for my own (elisp) code, but it's useful to know about.

Comment: @phils: Well, I would be interested in hearing how you think about this, but perhaps this is not the best venue for such discussion.